# how can to execute multiple actions in one line?

Tags: javascript, breeze

In my case I have one repository like this from temphire (breeze)

```
define(['durandal/system'], function (system) {

    var Repository = (function () {

        var repository = function (entityManagerProvider, entityTypeName, resourceName, fetchStrategy) {

           .........

            this.find = function (predicate) {
                var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                    .from(resourceName)
                    .where(predicate);

                return executeQuery(query);
            };

            function executeQuery(query) {
                return entityManagerProvider.manager()
                    .executeQuery(query.using(fetchStrategy || breeze.FetchStrategy.FromServer))
                    .then(function (data) { return data.results; });
            }

            ................

        };

        return repository;
    })();

    return {
        create: create,
        getCtor: Repository
    };

    function create(entityManagerProvider, entityTypeName, resourceName, fetchStrategy) {
        return new Repository(entityManagerProvider, entityTypeName, resourceName, fetchStrategy);
    }
});
```

NOW

HOW CAN DO LIKE SOME THIS

```
repository.query(predicate).execute();

function query(predicate) {
  return query = breeze.EntityQuery
  .from(resourceName)
  .where(predicate);
};

function executeQuery(query) {
  return entityManagerProvider.manager().executeQuery(query.using(fetchStrategy || breeze.FetchStrategy.FromServer)).then(function(data) {
    return data.results;
  });
}

function execute() -- >
  return executeQuery
```

the first action return query and after to execute

many thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  What are trying to do?

Comment: Not sure this is what you are trying to do, but executeQuery() is returning a Q promise, so process data.results like this: executeQuery(someQuery).then(function(results){ alert(results); });

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with what you are trying is that `return` terminates execution. If you want to do something as well as return in that function, then you need to do it before you return.

If, on the other hand, you really need to return the value and *then* execute something, then you should have the method that calls the function expecting the return, call the function to get the return value, and then have *that* calling function execute the thing you want executed. If that execution needs some data from the function that returns the value, then return that information with the value returned, and pass it into the function that does the execution.

Comment: I want to be completely separate the query and results. 
because rep.query(pred1).where(pred2)....exec() <-results mayby must used prototype but I dont know how thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

> executeQueryLocally // This is syn

instead of

> executeQuery // This is async

[executeQuery sync](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_executeQueryLocally)